# Iterating through a string and comparing result to another string using .equals (Java)

Tags: java, string, if-statement, intellij-idea, string-comparison

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Landscape landscape = new Landscape();

        Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your terrain: ");

        String TerrainInput = keyboardScanner.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < TerrainInput.length(); i++){

            char j = TerrainInput.charAt(i);

            if j.**equals(**"m") {
                //landscape.mountain(int [j+1])
            }

            if j.**equals**("f"){
                //landscape.flat(int [j+1])
            }
            if j.**equals**("h"){
                //landscape.hill(int [j+1])
            }
        }

    landscape.print();
```

The program should receive some input string like `f3,m3,f2,m0,f4,h1,f1` 
my plan is to iterate through each character and check if it is equal "f,m, or h"
and if it is then i will call the appropriate method and use the number after "f,m, or h" as an argument by calling the method with the index of the letter character found + 1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < TerrainInput.length(); i++){
    char j = TerrainInput.charAt(i);

    if j.**equals(**"m") {
        //landscape.mountain(int [j+1])
    }
}
```

The issue is the .equals isn't working, its saying `Cannot resolve method 'equals(java.lang.String)'`

Comment: I apologize if post sucks... im new to this site.

Comment: char is a primitive, not a class object

Answer (score 0):

`j` is a char, not a String. Chars are compared using `==`, not `equals`

```
if (j == 'm')
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is different than Python and JavaScript. `charAt` doesn't return a `String`, it returns a `char` (exclusively a character). Therefore you can't compare it to a `String`. If you write a character in single quotes, that will be a `char` like this: `'a'`. Also, `char` is a primitive type, so you can compare with `==`.